# Change drupalsite/user to drupalsite/customadmin

Tags: 7, users

Currently to login as an admin I need to navigate to the URL `http://drupal.mysite.com/user` and then I am logging in with userid **admin**.

I want to change the `user` part of the URL to my own custom URL containing `customadmin`, so that I can navigate to my login page with URL `http://drupal.mysite.com/customadmin` (instead of URL `http://drupal.mysite.com/user`).

I know there are some core file that can be changed to do this, like:

```
'H:\xampp\htdocs\mydrupal\modules\user\user.module'
```

I.e by modifying the hook menu for login like so:

```
/**
   * Custom menu for login
   */
  $items['customadmin'] = array(
    'title' => 'User account',
    'title callback' => 'user_menu_title',
    'page callback' => 'user_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
    'weight' => -10,
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
  );
```

But I wonder if there is some other way to do this (instead of making changes in core files, which is not recommended of course).

Comment: I find your question a bit bizar, but not inappropriate. Do not worry too much about downvotes on SE. Rather consider them as opinion epressions. Also note that it does not "cost" any reputation to downvote a question, while downvoting an answer costs -1 to the downvoter. However, a downvote to a question or an answer always costs -2 to the author of the question or answers. So downvoting questions is cheap (at no cost). so why bother? Also: if you only get 1 upvote (like mine ...), it compensates for 5 downvotes (5 * (-2) = -10) ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens : Thanks for information and upvote ;)

Comment: You're Welcome! Also at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22624/new-user-experience-for-drupal-answers ... And note 'somebody' also upvoted your comment already ... Right!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not edit core files (ever).

You can do this without code by setting a path alias for the /**user** path.

Go to **admin/config/search/path/add** and add the alias *customadmin* for existing path *user*:

[image]

Now if you go go to /customadmin you will see the login or user page. If you want to ensure that that the /user path also redirects to /customadmin, just enable the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module (no configuration needed).

Comment: Sry for late reply Will setting`path alias ` disable `/user` i dnt want them to see login page if they are trying to navigate to `/user`

Comment: Oh got it .....just have to redirect user to custom admin.....thanks

Comment: Everything working fine, how do I make `/user` to show 404 instead of `/customadmin` whole purpose of this was to hide the `adminurl` from third person

Comment: You could just put a redirect for /user in your .htaccess I suppose. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I dnt want others to reach my admin login page....it was to try to make site more secure @autopoietic

Comment: Strong passwords and disabling user registration should accomplish this without worrying about whether someone can locate the login.

Comment: hmmmm... Thanks @autopoietic for suggestion, I am already making strong password, I will also disable user registration